# Kotlin inline function for checking if user is autheticated or not?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, kotlin-coroutines

I want to execute a block of code after checking if user is authenticated or not. Something like this:

```
   inline fun <T : Any, R> T?.isUserAuthenticated(callback: (T) -> R) {
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.let {
        //Function call
    } ?: kotlin.run {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInAnonymously().addOnSuccessListener { 
            //Function call
        }
    }
```

This approach isn't working, but is there any alternative to this?

Comment: If you want to be able to pass an inline function parameter into another scope, it has to be marked as `crossinline` (so the compiler knows that it isn’t called in place at the call site and therefore cannot have non-local returns in it). I can’t tell what you’re attempting to do with generics but it doesn’t look like it makes sense. Why is this an extension function on absolutely everything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inline functions in Kotlin should be used over regular functions when:

- You desperately need to allocate memory more efficiently.
- When a function accepts another function or lambda as an argument.
- You need to prevent object creation and have better control flow.

Otherwise, inlining [may cause the generated code to grow](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-functions.html). Most likely there are also other situations when it is worth using inline functions but I only added a few (important) of them.

When it comes to checking if a user is authenticated or not, I would rather create a regular function that looks like this:

```
fun getAuthState() = auth.currentUser != null
```

And use it:

```
val isAuthenticated = getAuthState()
if(!isAuthenticated) {
    auth.signInAnonymously().addOnCompleteListener(/*...*/)
}
```

Or if using Kotlin Coroutine:

```
if(!isAuthenticated) {
    auth.signInAnonymously().await()
}
```

So it's one approach or the other.

I would add this function in a repository class so it can be used all across the entire project.

If you're interested in seeing some code, I recommend you check the following resource:

- [How to handle Firebase Authentication in clean architecture using Jetpack Compose?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-handle-firebase-authentication-in-clean-architecture-using-jetpack-compose-e9929c0e31f8)

And here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseAnonymousAuthentication).

Comment: Really brilliant explanation! Not only did your answer solve my current issue, I was also able to learn a lot about Clean Architecture and how to implement it in a Compose application.

Comment: Good to hear that, Saad. And you're very welcome.

Comment: If you want to learn more about Jetpack Compose, maybe this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-make-a-clean-architecture-android-app-using-mvvm-firestore-and-jetpack-compose-abdb5e02a2d8) will also help. Of course with the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreCleanArchitectureApp). This [series](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-android-app-using-firebase-part-1-4f305485e5d2) might also be helpful.